# Contact page disappear after save category

Tags: blocks, contact-us, page, contact-form

I have a online store in Magento 2.2.3 with i18n stores. In menu i create new Catalog Category with name: ***Contacts***, ***Contactos*** and ***Contacts*** in order ***EN***, ***PT*** and ***FR***. I configure this category to redirect for url key `contact`.

I use `rokanthemes` / `bs_cogito_1` and i have one xml with name `contact_inxex_index.html` in this file i make a reference to personalized block ***contact-info***.

```xml
<referenceContainer name="col.right.sidebar">
    <container name="contact.info" as="contact_info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="contact-info">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="contact-info">
           <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">contact-info</argument>
           </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

I have these blocks for three languages. Check bellow.

[image]

And in configuration path **Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Search engine optimizations** i removed .html from url, clear cache and flush cache, reindex all and rebuild static content.

[image]

configuration path **Stores > Configuration > General > Contacts** i enable ***Contact us***.

[image]

this already worked, but only for the portuguese language in the url ***/contact***, french and portuguese directed to contacts.html, when I edited the ***URL Key*** to `contact` the menus of all language direct to ***/contact***, but all content is gone.

thought that the contact stop in the url was reserved and always pointed to the xml file `contact_index_index`.

Any idea?